# How to target a parent of a parent of every element with a specific class

Tags: css

```html
<div>
    <span>
        <a class="theclass">Text here</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

In this example, I want to target the div from the class "theclass", not the div specifically but the parent of the parent, which is the div. I can't change the structure, just the CSS. Is that even possible?

Comment: There is no parent selector in CSS. You need to use Javascript/jQuery for this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:has` pseudo-class for this one, but it still works only in Safari. No way to do it using pure CSS in every browser. Would be better to handle it with JavaScript.